# Nested objects accessing owner properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, nested

Is it possible to access a property of an owner property?

For example:

```
@interface Site : NSObject

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString * siteName;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * visits;
```

The visits array is populated by n number Visit objects on creation. Each Visit object looks like this:

```
@interface Visit : NSObject

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSDate * visitDate;
@property(assign) int visitStatus;
```

Would it be possible to, in the Visit init or a class method, be able to get the Site property "siteName".

Implemented example:

```
Site * site1 = [[Site alloc]init];
site1.siteName = @"SITE NAME";

Visit * siteVisit1 = [[Visit alloc]init];
siteVisit1.visitDate =[NSDate date];
siteVisit1.visitStatus = ongoing;

[site1.visits addObject:siteVisit1];
```

Say I need to populate a UITableView with a list of sites and dates, something like this but more formatted.

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| Site Name | Visit Date | Visit Status |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| Site 1    | 7/8/2014   | planned      |
| Site 1    | 8/8/2014   | ongoing      |
| Site 1    | 9/8/2014   | ongoing      |
| Site 2    | 10/8/2014  | planned      |
| Site 2    | 11/8/2014  | ongoing      |
| Site 3    | 12/8/2014  | planned      |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

This table could be generated by going through each Site, and then another loop for each Visit.

```
NSMutableArray * tableViewData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (Site * site in siteArray){

    for(Visit * visit in site.visits){
        [tableViewData addObject:visit];
    }

}
```

I would then need to access the site name from each Visit object when populating the UITableView

```
Visit * visitForRow = [tableViewData objectAt:indexPath.row];

//Something like this
NSString * siteNameForVisit = [visitForRow getSiteName]; // To have the value "SITE NAME"

cell.siteLabel = siteNameForVisit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement this, you need to keep Site object reference in Visit interface. You can follow as below

```
\#import "Visit.h"
// Site.h
@interface Site : NSObject
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString * siteName;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * visits;
-(Visit*) createVisit;
@end

// Site.m

@imlementation Site

-(Visit*) createVisit{
    Visit * siteVisit = [[Visit alloc]initWithSite:self];
    return siteVisit;
}
@end


// Visit.h
@interface Visit : NSObject
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSDate * visitDate;
@property(assign) int visitStatus;
-(id)initWithSite:(id)site;
@end



\#import "Site.h"
// Visit.m

@interface Visit : NSObject
@property(weak, nonatomic) Site * site;
@end

@imlementation Visit
-(id)initWithSite:(Site*)site{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        _site = site;
       }
    return self;
}
-(NSString*)getSiteName
{
    return self.site.siteName;
}
@end
```

Comment: Close and a good idea. But XCode won't have it. I can't import Visit into Site and Site into Visit at the same time. It throws a generic error.

Comment: @Pillbox you can do it. You need not to import Site.h file in to Visit.h file. I have edited my answer check how it is done

Comment: This is correct, but the Visit.m needs to have the initWithSite to be: -(id)initWithSite(id)site.

Comment: @Pillbox it depend on you how do you want to write a code to solve your purpose, Alternate you can use simple -(id)init;,  then later you can set Site as -(void)setSite:(id)site;